# Как изменить цвет бордера активного/неактивного окна в UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

При фокусе и разфокусе у активного окна в Uwp есть небольшой бордер темный у активного окна и светлый у неактивного:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли как-то задать его цвет для обоих состояний?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Change UWP window border color?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41195252/12888024)

> You can't, this color is determined by the system accent color in the Settings app. You can only change the title bar color for your app.

**Перевод**

Вы не сможете, этот цвет задается как цвет акцента в Настройках операционной системы. Можно только изменить цвет заголовка окна для вашего приложения.